# OBSOLETE - Stack Up for iOS (1.0.1)

Tags: app, obsolete, iphone

> ## OBSOLETE - the app is not available anymore in the App Store

### About

*Stack Up is now available on the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/stack-up/id383709484).*

Stack Up is a Stack Exchange client for iOS (4.0 only at the moment, but I'm working on adding iPad support). You can learn a little more about it [here](http://www.stackupapp.com), or keep updated by following this currently very barren twitter account: [@stackupapp](http://twitter.com/stackupapp).

### Features

*1.0.1 is available now.*

**Version 1.0.1**

- Fixed an issue where changing answers would sometimes crash
- Answers now include activity and creation dates

**Version 1.0**

- Works with Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, the meta sites and the beta sites
- Browse questions by type, tag or author
- Integrates with twitter, Instapaper, Safari and Mail
- Read answers with an intuitive Mail-like UI
- Search for questions, tags, users and badges
- Includes high-resolution graphics for Retina display
- Save your favorite questions offline

**Future**

I'm working on adding iPad support and a push notification server, both of which *should* be ready soon (hopefully late August/early September). If you want to request a feature or think something is horribly broken please let me know here, by email or on twitter.

Also, I'm considering adding a free version which would either be lightly ad-supported or lacking some features. Let me know if this is something you're interested in.

#### Screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

### License

Commercial; available on the App Store for $1.99.

### Download

Available now on the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/stack-up/id383709484).

### Platform

Currently iOS 4.0 only, with 3.2/iPad support coming soon. If there are a bunch of people still using 3.x and aren't eager to upgrade to 4.0 let me know and I'll try to work something out.

### Contact

You can learn a little more about Stack Up [here](http://www.stackupapp.com) and me [here](http://www.conormulligan.com). If you have ideas I'd love to hear them; you can sound off with comments or answers, or get in touch directly by sending an email to *conor (at) conormulligan.com*. I've also set up a twitter account ([@stackupapp](http://twitter.com/stackupapp)) where I'd like to push updates and solicit feedback.

### Code

Objective-C; the Stack Exchange framework is my own which I'm hoping to open-source soon once it's worthy.

Comment: out of curiosity when did you submit it, there's another iphone app here and I wondered how long it takes?
Btw, I understand if this is your job but isn't $2.99 a little much for an app? - Neverhteless it looks great!!!

Comment: Looks like a very nice app... a tad dear though, I must say. I would gladly pay $1.00 or even $1.50, but $3 is pushing it.

Comment: I agree with @Noldorin.  Plus, the other iOS app (six to eight) is free when it comes out

Comment: @Jonathan, I submitted it last Tuesday so about 7 working days in total. In my experience they never really take longer than 10 working days without letting you know if there's a problem.

Comment: Hey guys, the price is mainly to cover the (eventual) cost of running a push notification server and to justify the time I’d like to spend on adding iPad support. However, I don’t want people to feel like I’m ripping them off so I’m going to drop the price to $1.99 and put the app on sale for 99c from now until the 8th of August.

Comment: @conmulligan: Sounds pretty fair to me, now. :)

Comment: You guys are seriously bitching about paying $3 for someones hard work? My goodness remind me not to get into iPhone app development...

Comment: but on iOS it tends to be the huge amount of downloads that make the money, becuase there are so many devices and its so easy to buy from the app store. But anyway the app is great!! and thanks for making an offer :) If you needed to make more money to run a push notification server you could always make the ability to receive push notifications an in app purchase.

Comment: @Farseeker: That's not at all how people think.

Comment: whats the plan for the ipad version will we need to buy that separately ? or will it be a universal app and if I buy the iphone version now will i need to re-purchase ? I'm not complaining just want to know

Comment: @mcgrailm It'll be a universal app, for my own sanity as much as anything else.

Comment: @conmulligan  thanks for the heads up are there any plans to let people login ? slos I noticed that when i searched a tag and and selected it i got old topics that had new answers first rather than just the newest topics is that intentional ?

Comment: @mcgrailm, the API is read-only at the moment so logging in isn't possible per se; however, version 1.1 will allow you to associate sites with users and track their changes. By default, a tag search will list questions by activity; this is by design, but in 1.1 I'll allow you to change the sort order. I'll update the question above soon with more info on what's coming.

Comment: your site, stackupapp.com is flagged as hopsting malware (not saying it does), this means that google chrome users who go to your website are stopped with a huge red stop page, including chrome users who come to this question as the images are hosted on your site. You should probably remove whatever triggered google to flag it, or contact google.

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks for the heads up! Someone injected some nasty code into a .js file. I've removed the malicious stuff and requested a review.

Comment: Sweet! When are push notifications coming? And what will they support?

Comment: @balupton, initially I'd like to have notifications for reputation changes and new answers/comments on asked or favourite questions. If there's anything else you think might be useful, let me know!

Comment: There’s only one price which won’t make *someone* complain that something is too expensive, and that’s free.